# Unit Test AsyncTask.execute not working

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio

I know a lot of code already in stackoverflow but i cant run this :

```
@Test
    public void startAsyncTask() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("startAsyncTask");
        final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

        final AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            public Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                System.out.println("DO SOMETHING ON BACKGROUND");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                super.onPostExecute(o);
                System.out.println("onPostExecute");
                signal.countDown();
            }
        };
        System.out.println("EXECUTE");
        task.execute();
        signal.await();
    }
```

Very very simple code and i cant launch him in Android Unit test.
I tried

> InstrumentalCase, ActivityCase, ApplicationCase,

i also tried run

> runTestOnUIThread

but everytime i have one result : task.execute not launched/called. Please someone can help me ?

Comment: AsyncTasks are queued per app, when you don't specify otherwise. Perhaps this function is called within another AsyncTask that blocks the queue?

Comment: i dont have other functions. Only this one. ONE

Comment: Please do not delete posts as you also deleted my answer. I already told you that the signature of doInBackground is wrong. You continue as if that has not been said. What are you up to?

Comment: @greenapps question which was deleted was not constructive. No sense in him

Comment: @greenapps u suggestion about doInBackground is wrong. Its not help and not make sense. This override method 1) bulded by astudio 2) i tried also your "answer"